# Google sheet protect based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have like 30 tabs in one google sheet file and all of them have the same structure but different data

I want a script that locks (protect) the whole sheet based on the value

this value is defined as range and I want to lock the tab if the value is (audited)

- cell position : A5
- cell value    : "audited"

Answer (score 1):

```
function protectAudited() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  shts.forEach(function(sh) {
    if(sh.getRange('A5').getValue()=='audited') {
      sh.protect();
    }
  });
}
```

Perhaps like this:

```
function protectAudited() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  shts.forEach(function(sh) {
    if(sh.getRange('A5').getValue()=='Audited') {
      sh.protect();
    }else {
      var protection=sh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
      if(protection && protection.canEdit()) {
        protection.remove();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: many many many thnx bro, last question :D, what is the function for un-protect the tab?

Comment: Here's an example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection.html#remove()) `// Remove sheet protection from the active sheet, if the user has permission to edit it.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var protection = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
if (protection && protection.canEdit()) {
  protection.remove();
}`

Comment: how can i use it in your code for else section 

function protectAudited() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  shts.forEach(function(sh) {
    if(sh.getRange('A5').getValue()== "Done") {
      sh.protect().setDescription("Can't edit the file after closing the finance");
    }else {
    
      *** unlock the protection 
    
    }
  });
}